# Itext embed font in a PDF

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, itext, foxit

I have a pdf that has been created using the Foxit form designer.  On my design system, I have the barcode font installed.  The barcode font is used in one of the AcroFields. It appears that foxit does not embed the font in the document.

I also have customers that do not have the barcode font installed in their computers, and thus I would like to embed the font into the PDF.  Is there a way for me to embed a font that is used in the AcroFields into the PDF using iText?

**EDIT:** The font seems to be included in the text, but not the fields, Therefore the font(barcode) will not print.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm almost sure that you got an answer by now, but maybe others would like to get a detailed view on the solution. Below is the sample java code  I used to embed fonts in the generated PDF (useful only in some cases, as the size of the documents increases dramatically). 
As a free tool to create the PDF forms, I have used the OpenOffice writer, by adding forms inside the documents and exporting the documents as PDF files :

```
PdfReader pdfTemplate = new PdfReader(templateName);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont(unicodeFontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfTemplate, out);
//assigning the font to the field
stamper.getAcroFields().setFieldProperty("myField", "textfont", unicode, null);
stamper.getAcroFields().setField("myField", someValue);
stamper.close();
pdfTemplate.close();
```

Comment: I'm met almost the same problem and I have done the same as you, but I still can't embed the font for those text I input using Java, can you have a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335481/how-to-embed-font-after-flattening-template-using-itext)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
PdfContentByte ab = yourPDFWriter.getDirectContent();
// field: PdfFormField.createTextField(...);
PdfAppearance ap = ab.createAppearance(320, 30); // size of field
field.setDefaultAppearanceString(ap);
```

That should do the trick.