# iTextSharp diacritics

Tags: c#, java, pdf, itext, diacritics

I am trying to typeset a pdf with iTextSharp library, but I cannot find anywhere how to handle diacritics. Since I found tables of contents of two books about iTextSharp where diacritics has a section, I suppose it is doable. So the question is

```
How to typeset "ř" ?
```

In addition, is there some guide or link about this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need to figure out what the Unicode representation is for your diacritical characters. You can embed [Unicode characters](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) into a string literal with \u[unicode value in hex]; e.g.

```
string s = "\u0159";  // Should be your character
```

You may also need to choose a font that can represent the characters correctly:

```
bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(...);
font = new Font(bf, 12);
document.Add(new Paragraph(s, font);
```

Comment: The problem was not exactly on the chosen font, but on the encoding. I didn't notice that previously, however thanks.
Btw as far as i know all strings in c# are translated into unicode characters.

Comment: True enough. In contrived code examples typically used in answers, we're often hard-coding strings, but in real use, the problem is often getting the encoding right when reading text into a string from an outside source (user input, text file, database, etc.)

Comment: here's the link for Romanian Unicode Diacritics   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-2

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to implement the answer sugested by **glaxaco**, but it did not work for me.

I've tried to fill out a pdf form with AcroFields, but the diacritics **ţşŢŞăîĂÎ** etc. would not apeear. (using **Arial** font)

In the end I've resorted to [stripping the diacritics](http://www.siao2.com/2007/05/14/2629747.aspx)

Pretty weird because when I introduce them by hand, as in MANUALLY filling in the forms, the diacritics show up just fine.

Hope someone can find a solution to this problem. `:(`

Comment: the `CreateFont` method has an overload with encoding => something like this `BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, false);`

Answer (score 0):

Diacritics are simply unicode characters. You will have to embed an unicode font into the PDF.
See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626632/itext-embed-font-in-a-pdf) for Java examples, I assume they will be almost the same in C#