# pdftk unicode works in preview but not adobe acrobat

Tags: pdf, unicode, utf-8, pdftk

I generate a PDF file and the unicode text appears in macos preview but not acrobat.

I have the following `fdf` file

```
%FDF-1.2
1 0 obj
<<
/FDF
<<
/Fields [
<<
/T (name)

/V <FEFF0793>
>>]
>>
>>
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R
>>
%%EOF
```

The main thing is `FEFF0793` which is `utf16be` encoded, and it should render the `ޓ` character (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0793)

```
pdftk form4.pdf fill_form fdf output 6.pdf
```

My [form4.pdf](https://www.mediafire.com/file/jnbkbpd18ebynkd/form4.pdf/file)

When I view it in MacOS preview, it doesn't appear until I click

[image]

[image]

but in acrobat it appears as a bullet point

[image]

Here is the fonts embedded. Whats the problem here? Why doesn't it appear in acrobat?

The font is from here: https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Thaana

It's added to my MacOS fontbook, so not sure whats happening here. What if I had custom fonts that aren't part of my fontbook but I want to use their unicode values. What do I do here?

[image]

Comment: @KJ  Why does it appear on preview but not acrobat? ive read using ghostscript we can embed fonts but couldnt get it to work

Comment: I have the font file avilable, a TTF as linked in the google fonts, and i try to embed using ghostscript but it did not work , i tried `gs -o 7.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dEmbedAllFonts=true -sFONTPATH=~/Library/Fonts/NotoSansThaana-Regular.ttf  6.pdf`

Comment: so can we fix this without ghostscript?

Comment: Can you post a link to the result PDF file (6.pdf)?

Comment: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/MauCLQL4#link

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Acrobat does not have a default font to be used with this script. Even after installing Non Sans Thaana in Windows, Acrobat cannot display the character.

The only solution is to associated the Thaana font with the form field when you create the form. This operation will embed the font in the PDF file and the form will be displayed correctly.
[image: Form field with Thaana font]
Embedding the font with Ghostscript like in your comment does not help as it does not associated the font with the form field.

The problem with pdftk is that it does not create appearances (explicit graphics for displaying the field value) for the form fields, it relies on the viewer to create them. Acrobat, with the embedded Thaana font, will create a proper appearance for the form field but other viewers might not create them.

Comment: My use case is that there are a few form fields (like name) that get their value from a database, which I need to then convert to a working pdf

Comment: The idea was that I would generate the form using pdftk (utf16 encoding for the name), and then embed a list of 10-20 fonts that contained characters from different languages. This would be done using ghostscript. Then when the final pdf is loaded, it has the fonts already because I embedded them through ghostscript

Comment: I've seen a few threads that we can use ghostscript for this, but you are saying this does not help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231656/how-do-i-embed-fonts-in-an-existing-pdf

Comment: @KSplitX Ghostscript helps when the font associated with the field is Thaana but the font is not embedded. In your file the font associated with the field is Helvetica and Ghostscript will not replace it with Thaana.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly, I have to make the field font itself as Thaana. I can add some Thaana text to initially get it embedded via acrobat. I can then generate an FDF, overwite the value, and save it via `pdftk`. The problem here is that initially a subset of Thaana will be embedded, but if I add more thaana text, more subset needs to be embedded. How can I do this doing ghostscript ? (might be a seperate question altogether)